# How to get the maximum number of digits after the decimal point in a Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read a list of float values of varying precision from a csv file into a Pandas Series and need the number of digits after the decimal point. So, for 123.4567 I want to get 4.

I managed to get the number of digits for randomly generated numbers like this:

`df = pd.Series(np.random.rand(100)*1000)
precision_digits = (df - df.astype(int)).astype(str).str.split(".", expand=True)[1].str.len().max()`

However, if I read data from disk using pd.read_csv where some of the rows are empty (and thus filled with nan), I get the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/tgamauf/workspace/mostly-sydan/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4376, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'`

What is going wrong here?
Is there a better way to do what I need?

Comment: You can fill the missing values beforehand missing `fillna` to prevent the mistake from happening, can't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.read_csv()` typically returns a `DataFrame` object.  The `StringMethods` object returned by using `.str` is only defined for a `Series` object.  Try using `pd.read_csv('your_data.csv' , squeeze=True)` to have it return a `Series` object; then you will be able to use `.str`

Comment: `squeeze=True` fixed the problem, but I noticed that it doesn't even apply if I load the whole dataframe and then select a single column (as I need to do anyway). In this case it actually works out of the box. Thank you anyway, as this does answer the question I posed!

Answer (score 0):

For example you have following data with `NaN` in it .

```
df=pd.Series([1.111,2.2,3.33333,np.nan])
```

---

```
idx=df.index# record the original index 
df=df.dropna()# remove the NaN row 
(df - df.astype(int)).astype(str).str.split(".", expand=True)[1].str.len().reindex(idx)
```

Comment: What does the `.reindex(idx)` do here? The result is the same for my current dataset if I used .max() or .reindex(idx).max().

Answer (score 0):

The version with `df - df.astype(int)` does not work correctly for me, simply applying the same `str.split` without it does:

```
def get_max_decimal_length(df):
    """Get the maximum length of the fractional part of the values or None if no values present."""
    values = df.dropna()
    return None if values.empty else values.astype(str).str.split(".", expand=True)[1].str.len().max()
```